# How to have console based application read input from seperate dialog box project in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, user-interface, dialog, console, user-input

I currently have an mfc based dialog box application and a console application both created in visual studio 2010 (right now they are separate). I was wondering how I can combine these two solutions so I can read the user input from the dialog box application and use it for the console based application. Once the user clicks "ok" on the dialog box GUI, the console based app should appear with information dependent on the user's input. Any example code would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since the two projects run in separate processes, you need some form of [interprocess communication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

There are many options.

[Named Pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is one alternative worth exploring.  It is simple to setup and use, and well suited to the task of one program communicating information to another program.  If you need bidirectional communication, that can be accomplished by setting up one named pipe for each direction.

Comment: My gui is just a simple dialog box. So, is it possible to merge the two projects? I could change the configuration settings in my console application to allow the use of mfc, and then add the resource files from my gui to my console app. And then somehow have the console application appear after the user presses ok on the gui? Thanks

Comment: If you are going to merge the projects, it would probably be simpler to merge whatever logic you need from the console project into the GUI project.